# Maximum and minimum of function in a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the points of maximum and minimum of the function $$f(x,y,z) = 2x + y - z^2$$ in the compact space 
$$C = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 4x^2 + y^2 -z^2 = -1,z\ge 0, 2z \le 2x + y + 4\}$$

So, I have the answer for this, which is:

Minimum: $$ -19 - 6\sqrt{7} $$
Maximum: $$ -\frac 12 $$

I already found the minimum value, but I'm having trouble to find the maximum.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: Isn't this just Lagrange Multiplers?

Comment: It is, but because of the inequality I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do @jip

Comment: How were you able to find the min then?

Comment: By the usual way, I found the point where f equals to the minimum because I had the answer to check, but I didn't find another point. @jip

Answer (score 0):

hint:

$t=2x+y,z^2-1=4x^2+y^2 \ge \dfrac{t^2}{2} \implies f\le t-\dfrac{t^2}{2} -1$

$z\le \dfrac{t+4}{2} \implies \left(\dfrac{t+4}{2} \right)^2-1 \ge\dfrac{t^2}{2} $